# Clickable link area unexpectedly smaller after CSS transform

Tags: html, css, transform

I have an unordered list with a few list items that act as flip cards using CSS 3D transforms. I want them to flip via clicks on links/anchor elements inside of the list items, and these links fill up the entire list item as well.

The list items look and act fine in their default non-flipped state, but once I click one and it flips, the clickable link area on the back side of it is only on the top half of the list item. When I inspect in Chrome, the link area is still filling up the entire height of the list item, so I'm not sure what is going on.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chucknelson/B8aaR/

Below is a summary of the transform properties I'm using on various elements (see fiddle for detail):

```
-webkit-transition: 0.6s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 1.5em;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
```

Note that I'm testing in Chrome 28 on Windows, and I'm just using -webkit prefix items in the fiddle. I also apologize for any messy CSS or markup, this problem had me iterating a bit. Any help in understanding what is happening is greatly appreciated!

**Update 8/11/2013:**
I was having this same problem with a 2D transforms on list items (just flipping the item, no front/back). Adding @thirtydot's translateZ(1px) transform in the CSS for the `<a>` tag fixed that one too. So it looks like the issue is related to the z-axis...but only on part of the link. Maybe this is a bug in browsers?

Comment: I am working on it. The gist is, it's only clicking the link basically, not the div. We want the div to be clickable.

Comment: I'm curious to know why the link doesn't remain the same, it's fully clickable in one state, and has the same properties in the inspector in the flipped state.

Comment: @Kyle: Wondering the same thing. Removing the <li> from that particular flipped container messes up everything but it does tell you one thing, those divs become fully clickable once again. Something to think about.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/YCGjZ/7/

Comment: Thanks Ali and Kyle. @thirtydot - that fiddle is interesting. The link is partially hidden/buried on the Z-axis? Still don't understand why it would only be part of the link, but that is definitely one workaround option - thanks!

Comment: It's almost certainly a WebKit bug, there will probably already be an existing bug report somewhere. You should try to find it to see if there are any better solutions, otherwise report the bug yourself. I apply the "fix" with JavaScript because having it in the CSS seems to screw up your transition. My "fix" is not based on any kind of logic, it was just an idea I had after trying a lot of different things to try to determine the source of the problem.

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks, I'll go check bug reports.

Comment: So was this problem solved?  Remember to post your answer as an answer and not just comments.  That way it can easily be marked as the answer (which helps future people searching this problem).

Comment: @Fernker I'll check for bugs today, and if I find nothing I'll post the method via thirtydot that gets around the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem may be the result of a webkit rendering bug, but the solution was to tranlsate the link's Z-axis by 1px - this seemed to push the link layer up and have it fully clickable.

To fix the 3D transform (via the fiddle from @thirtydot http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/YCGjZ/7/), some javascript was required:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        flipTarget.find('div.back a').css('-webkit-transform', 'translateZ(1px)');
        flipTarget.find('div.back a').css('transform', 'translateZ(1px)');
    }, 600);
```

When using a 2D transform, adding translateZ in the CSS class worked:

```
.flipped {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #555;

    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flipped a {
    color: #eee;
    text-decoration: line-through;

    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1) translateZ(1px); /* the fix */
}
```