# Clickable area in buttons with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking at this example: http://codepen.io/benague/pen/bCkyr

```
.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

When you click these buttons at the very top, it doesn't really grab the link, but they still get animated.

How can I increase the clickable area so that whenever it animates, it actually goes to the URL?

Thank you.

Comment: can't reproduce the problem in FF

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
#buttons a {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1) translateZ(-1px);
}
```

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyYmvJ

---

Reason for the link not fully clickable could be because the **transform property** on your active buttons kind of moved the anchor link a bit.

---

The issue here: [Clickable link area unexpectedly smaller after CSS transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167981/clickable-link-area-unexpectedly-smaller-after-css-transform) is simlar to yours so check out the correct answer there to get a better explanation regarding the transform property affecting the position of the anchor link and also regarding the fix.

Comment: That fixed the problem. But the cute animation (clickable button) in the original example is gone :( It doesn't seem like pressed buttons anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working properly. But if I understand you right you want to remove the padding of the link. You could use to remove the `padding: 15px 25px;` from `.btn` and work with

```
a {
 height: 60px;
 width: 160px;
}
```

or something

Comment: Hmm that's not it. If you click at the very top of the button, it animates as if you had clicked, but doesn't really go to the link.